# Problem on setting error message if insert fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

When doing add activity inside store method, after passing validation I am calling a method that returns success or failure. 
But on failure, I am not able to handle the code properly.
If I redirect, am not getting the old value.
So How do i return to **create** method with error message & old value both?
Any way to populate the **$errors** array?

Am new to Laravel. Thanks in advance

```
public function store(Request $request, AppMailer $mailer)
    {
        $validatedData=$request->validate([
            .......
            ........
        ]);

        $tracking_model = new Tracking;
        $result  = $tracking_model->add($request->all());

        if ($result === true) {

            return redirect('posts')->with('success', 'Created Successfully');

        }
        else{
            $err_msgs = $result;            
           //what to do here ???????

            // return redirect('posts/create')->with('error', $err_msgs);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this 
in the controller

```
return redirect('posts/create')->withInput()->withErrors($err_msgs);
```

and in view `.blade`

```
  @if ($errors->any())
      @foreach ($errors as $error)
        ...
     @endforeach
  @else
    No tags
  @endif
```